# What hash method need to use generate password_hash - Magento2

Tags: magento-2.1, password

I have a situation to write **java** code to match **password_hash** field as like **customer_entity** table. After read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12803180/5528059) I have tried with **SHA256** but the result was different also I have tried with **MD5**, it also does not match with **password_hash** field.

I have used this [online generator tool](http://www.lorem-ipsum.co.uk/hasher.php), it list most of the hash method but none of the result match with **password_hash** of **customer_entity** table.

I'm looking for your suggestion what is the exact hash method I need to use?, it should be match with **password_hash** field of **customer_entity** table.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because `password_hash` can automatically generate `salt`, and that automatically generated `salt` might not be matching the `salt` generated or specified in your Java-based tool.

Check: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

> salt - to manually provide a salt to use when hashing the password. Note that this will override and prevent a salt from being automatically generated.
>
> If omitted, a random salt will be generated by password_hash() for each password hashed. This is the intended mode of operation.

Also check this warning:

> The salt option has been deprecated as of PHP 7.0.0. It is now preferred to simply use the salt that is generated by default.